# Инициализация массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Почему такая инициализация массива допустима:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};
```

а вот такая нет:

```
int[] array;
array = {1,2,3};
```

Вроде бы можно сказать, что способы вполне эквиваленты.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Так определено в языке.

Синтаксис `int[] array = {1,2,3};` — это *инициализация*, целостное выражение, которое не есть «присваивание `array` значения `{1, 2, 3}`», а «инициализация массива значениями 1, 2, 3».

А `array = {1, 2, 3};` — это присваивание. Но правая часть тут вовсе не определена в языке, инициализатор не имеет самостоятельного смысла.

Вы можете, однако, присвоить так:

```
int[] array;
array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

Здесь правая часть `new int[] {1, 2, 3}` — нормальный, инициализированный объект.

---

В принципе, язык *мог бы* определить `{1, 2, 3}` как литерал массива, то есть, чтобы это имело такое же значение, как `new int[] {1, 2, 3}`. Но дизайнеры языка посчитали это излишним.

Мне кажется, они руководствовались таким соображением: для литералов целых чисел (типа `5`) нет особой разницы, писать ли

```
int x = 5;
int y = 5;
```

или

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
```

А вот для литералов массива (который есть ссылочный тип) разница была бы: вот такой гипотетический код

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
int[] y = {1, 2, 3};
x[0] = 10;
System.out.println(y[0]);
```

и

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
int[] y = x;
x[0] = 10;
System.out.println(y[0]);
```

вели бы себя по-разному! И это приводило бы к ошибкам и недопониманию. Но это лишь мои догадки.

Comment: да, насчет array = new int[] {1, 2, 3}; было известно, но хотелось было узнать на счет array = {1,2,3};
спасибо за вашу крутость, теперь все стало на свои места.

Comment: @dDevil: Пожалуйста! Дополнил ответ.

Comment: да, я активно слежу за изменениями в ответе, очень интересно читать мысли золотых умов stackoverflow) спасибо еще раз

Comment: @dDevil: Вы нас захвалите :) Просто если отвечать на вопросы, знания накапливаются быстрее, честно.

Answer (score 6):

Фактически, данное предложение

```
array = {1,2,3};
```

не является инициализацией создаваемого массива. Это предложение выражения с оператором присваивания, причем в правой части имеется конструкция, которая не является выражением. А оператор присваивания требует в правой части от знака `=` некоторое выражение.